# Compare date to month-year in Postgres/Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have a date column in my table and I would like to 'filter'/select out items after a certain year-month. So if I have data from 2010 on, I have a user input that specifies '2011-10' as the 'earliest date' they want to see data from.

My current SQL looks like this:

```
select round(sum(amount), 2) as amount,
date_part('month', date) as month
from receipts join items
on receipts.item = items.item
where items.expense = ?
    and date_part('year', date)>=2014
    and funding = 'General'
group by items.expense, month, items.order
order by items.order desc;
```

In the second part of the 'where', instead of doing year >= 2014, I want to do something like `to_char(date, 'YY-MMMM') >= ?` as another parameter and then pass in '2011-10'. However, when I do this:

```
costsSql = "select round(sum(amount), 2) as amount,
to_char(date, 'YY-MMMM') as year_month
from receipts join items
on receipts.item = items.item
where items.expense = ?
    and year_month >= ?
    and funding = 'General'
group by items.expense, year_month, items.order
order by items.order desc"
```

and call that with my two params, I get a postgres error: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "year_month" does not exist`.

Edit: I converted my YYYY-MM string into a date and passed that in as my param instead and it's working. But I still don't understand why I get the 'column does not exist' error after I created that column in the select clause - can someone explain? Can columns created like that not be used in where clauses?

Comment: Why not use `date >= ?::date` and pass in `2011-10-01`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error: `column "year_month" does not exist` happens because `year_month` is an **alias** defined the SELECT-list and such aliases can't be refered to in the WHERE clause.

This is based on the fact that the SELECT-list is evaluated after the WHERE clause, see for example: [Column alias in where clause?](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/48A3102C.8090403@wykids.org) for an explanation from PG developers.

Some databases allow it nonetheless, others don't, and PostgreSQL doesn't. It's one of the many portability hazards between SQL engines.

In the case of the query shown in the question, you don't even need the `to_char` in the WHERE clause anyway, because as mentioned in the first comment, a direct comparison with a date is simpler and more efficient too.

When a query has a complex expression in the SELECT-list and repeating it in the WHERE clause looks wrong, sometimes it might be refactored to move the expression into a sub-select or a WITH clause at the beginning of the query.